# How to underline a text using PdfContentByte in itextsharp

Tags: itext

This is actually in reference to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10738187/1206052) which is actually closed

Iam using ItextSharp 5.2.1.

I want to make my header text underlined using PdfContentByte. Please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private PdfContentByte pdfContentByte;



 private string DescriptionToPrint="Hii!! I will be underlined."
  private Int32  AlignmentofDescription = 3;
  private float  XofDescription = 110;
  private float  YofDescription = 440;
  private float  RotationofDescription = 0;
```

to write PDF using pdfcontentbyte we generally use the following

(begin text &
end text)

format

```
pdfContentByte.BeginText();
    pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, DescriptionToPrint.ToString(), XofDescription, YofDescription, RotationofDescription);
    pdfContentByte.EndText();
```

There is an alternative for the above technique also, which is quiet flexible too.

This is if you want the same formatting that you have applied to `pdfcontentbyte` using `BaseFont`

```
//ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(DescriptionToPrint), XofDescription, YofDescription, RotationofDescription);
```

If you want to underline the text, then inside `Phrase` place `Chunk`

```
  ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(new Chunk(DescriptionToPrint.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.UNDERLINE))), XofDescription, YofDescription, RotationofDescription);
```

here the line mentioned below is actually the fix.

```
new Phrase(new Chunk(DescriptionToPrint.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.UNDERLINE)))
```

For ColumnText we have to provide the text using `new Phrase`  in which we can access font properties which actually `base font` was not allowing
us to access.

Inside `Phrase` `Chunk` is providing the required formatting to the text.

Their are lots of examples available on net regarding use of `chunk`

If you want to pass **float values** like this(20.25)
these will be recognized as double by this class
use **"20.25f"** then they will be taken as float and will work...